# Disabling file-level namespacing in Apache Thrift

Tags: thrift

In its interface definition language, Apache Thrift automatically puts included declarations in a namespace sharing the name of the included file.
Can this be turned off?

For example, say you declare `Foo` in `myfoos.thrift` and in `mybars.thrift` you `include "myfoos.thrift"`.
Then in `mybars.thrift`, you will have access to `myfoos.Foo`, not `Foo`.

Comment: Is there a specific problem with it? Why are you asking this question?

Comment: Yes. It makes refactoring across files harder. It also introduces an inconsistency in the Thrift IDL (e.g the symbol `myfoos.Foo` is not defined in `myfoos.thrift`).

Answer (score 0):

No, this is part of the IDL design.

It should be mentioned however, that this namespace is only used for the IDL references. 
The namespace of the generated code is set

- either by an explicit `namespace` statement
- or implicitly by the IDL filename otherwise.